# Redirect after logout based on a query string

Tags: 7

I have an URL http://localhost/drupal/user?ReturnTo=.....

i would like to check that query string "ReturnTo" and if that exists, then I want drupal to load that URL, that URL will be a fully qualified URL which could be another domain, Example https://www.google.com

How to achieve this, i tried to use "Configure an advanced action" arbitrary PHP script, but always getting errors

Comment: You can use the ‘destination’ query string I believe. But maybe not. I’m not certain, it’s been a while since I’ve tried this.

Comment: unfortunately "ReturnTo" query string cannot be changed

Comment: Why not? Otherwise you probably have to build a route subscriber alter or something of that sort.